# GIMP: Select full (transparent) image

Tags: gimp, transparency

Not that good at GIMP, but I'm having an issue. I'm trying to copy from a transparent image to another, however it only copies the part that's **not** transparent. How can I make it also select and copy the part that is transparent, because I have half-opaque pixels there which it's not copying.

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to GD! It would be most helpful if you could add some screenshots and show us what you have tried and where exactly you get stuck. This saves everybody time, and makes it more likely that you will get helpful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is probably going on is that the target image is not in RGB mod, rather in indexed mode. (It will be so if its file in disk is indexed, like a GIF or an indexed PNG).

GIMP does not represent semi-transparency levels on indexed images - change the target image to RGB mode in `image->mode->RGB`  before pasting your contents there.

If afterwards you need to export the image to the same file format, you may want to manually convert the image back to indexed mode so that you can fine-tune the results before exporting.